# Excel Mac 2011 - X-Axis Position

Tags: macos, excel

I'd like to make a bar chart in Excel 2011 for my Mac and position the x-axis so that the labels are on the left of each column, not in the center. In the below picture, they are in the center. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how this flows in the Mac version but in Excel 2007 (Windows) the setting you want is on the X-axis formatting options: `Position Axis | On tick marks`

Now, after that step you may find the right and left columns to be cut off in an unpleasant way. The fix for this is to add a blank row above and below the chart data area and extend the chart series to include these blank rows. Final result:

[image]